# How to debug Azure Cosmos DB Stored Procedures?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Azure Cosmos DB, I am programming the client side in C# (web service) and I'm writing some server side Stored Procedures with java-script.

How can I debug my stored procedure's code?

Thanks,

MAK

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure is JS script running on the server, you can not debug it on your side.

However , you can use `console.log ()` to log some key steps in your stored procedure as below.

[image]

Then use [getScriptLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.storedprocedureresponse-1.scriptlog?view=azure-dotnet) to get the output from stored procedure `console.log()` statements.

Please note that `EnableScriptLogging = true`  is necessary to print console.log:

```
var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(
    document.SelfLink,
    new RequestOptions { EnableScriptLogging = true } );
Console.WriteLine(response.ScriptLog);
```

You could refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.enablescriptlogging?view=azure-dotnet).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: your answer is good , it's give a good work around for that, but some problem , if we received unhandled exception the logger will not help us , another thing , we need to add the  <system.net> 
        <settings> 
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" /> 
        </settings> 
    </system.net> to the web setting

Comment: @MAK Yes, stored procedure js code runs at server side so that we can not  debug it step by step.

Comment: @JayGong is it possible to run the sproc from within the Azure portal and view the logs there?