# Document Db Stored Procedure WIth Continuation Token Fails to Update All Records

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, document-database

I am trying to set the property of all documents of a particular user to false.
I am using Stored Procedure to do the same.
The Below Procedure fetches only a partial of the records and updates them.

I have a total of 2399 documents. But the Procedure fetches only 1332 and updates them.

```
function spBulkUpdateTrackInventory(tenantId) {
    var queryDocument = " select * from c where c.tenantId = '" + tenantId + "'";
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    var responseBody = {
        updatedCount: 0,
        continuation: true
    };

    fetchProducts();

    function fetchProducts(continuation) {

        var requestOptions = { continuation: continuation, pageSize:-1};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), queryDocument, requestOptions,
            function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
                if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

                if (retrievedDocs.length > 0)
                {
                    updateTrackInventory(retrievedDocs, responseOptions.continuation);
                }
            });
        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(responseBody);
    }

    function updateTrackInventory(documents, continuation) {
            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < documents.length; cnt++)
            {
                newdocument = documents[cnt];
                newdocument.trackInventory = true;
                responseBody.updatedCount++;
                var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(documents[cnt]._self, newdocument);

                if (!isAccepted) {
                    response.setBody(responseBody);
                }
            }

            if (continuation) {
                fetchProducts(continuation);
            }
        responseBody.continuation = false;
        response.setBody(responseBody);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can u check if there was 429 errors during your sp execution? what is the response.StatusCode value?

Comment: @sham Hi,any progress now?

Comment: @JayGong , On Prod Environment, none of the users have these many records. Did not get a chance to look into it

Comment: @sham Waiting for your test result...

Comment: @sham Any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

I created `3000` documents which are half-partitioned by `name` partition key to test your code.It works fine.

[image]

I suggest you checking if the SQL result is consistent running in stored procedure and in query shell.In addition, you could follow this case [How to debug Azure Cosmos DB Stored Procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855094/how-to-debug-azure-cosmos-db-stored-procedures/47861690#47861690) : to use `console.log` to debug your stored procedure.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Resource Units (RU) limit at either the Cosmos DB resource level and/or the container level is limiting the number of documents that the stored proc can query and update a single execution. Try bumping up the number at both these levels (subject to additional charges) and retesting the stored proc.