# How to Query Database through Stored Procedure in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a stored procedure that my app can call to run operations on a SQL cosmos DB in azure. I'm developing this using the Azure portal.

I generated a sample procedure, which is shown below.

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

When I run this, I get no results, but I created a single document in the documents section under the same tree as this stored procedure. When I run the stored procedure, I get no results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure code is totally as same as the sample code on the portal. It works fine without any issues.

[image]

Maybe you could check following points:

1.check whether the document is under the same collection with stored procedure.(just close other unrelated tags and check again!)

2.check if the sql `select * from root r` could grab the data on the portal.

3.try to create a new collection and a new stored procedure then check if the situation is constant.

4.try to use `console.log()` to debug and follow the stored procedure, please refer to my previous case: [How to debug Azure Cosmos DB Stored Procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855094/how-to-debug-azure-cosmos-db-stored-procedures/47861690#47861690)

---

Just for summary, we also need to check if we miss the partition key when we execute query sql!

Comment: Hey, I discovered the problem. I was missing a partition key in the document I was trying to query.

Comment: @jaredad7 Sure,I add the solution into my answer,you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.